# Android Wear: How to make translucent peek cards more transparent?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-cardview

Is there a way to increase the transparency level of translucent peek cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, peek cards are controlled by the system.

Comment: Sorry to hijack. But I have an app I have forked where the card notification backgrounds are transparent when the screen is dimmed. Are you able to point me to the command to make the background opaque in this situation? I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature. But am new at android wear so will have to basically do a search and replace.

Comment: @square_eyes the watch face developer gets to decide whether your card is translucent or opaque, which the system then uses to draw the card. It is not something you, as the one posting a notification, have control over

Comment: Ah cool thanks for the info. The code I have access to is actually the watch face :) I just don't know where to look or what to look for.

Comment: @square_eyes - then you'll want to look at [WatchFaceStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/watchface/WatchFaceStyle.html) - perhaps [AMBIENT_PEEK_MODE_VISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/watchface/WatchFaceStyle.html#AMBIENT_PEEK_MODE_VISIBLE) is what you're after? Of course, in ambient mode, any solid background won't be shown for [burn in protection](https://developer.android.com/design/wear/watchfaces.html#SpecialScreens)